# How do I reseed the ID increment in Rally using the Rally API?

Tags: rally

I accidentally added some defects to the wrong Workspace.  Now the ID's are too high.  I will be deleting the defects that are not supposed to be there, but after I do that, the next defect added will have an ID that continues from the last highest (even though it does not exist).  Is there a way to reset the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the FormattedID generator for each Rally workspace cannot be reset (even if/when you delete the defects added). I don't know of any other way around this issue.